# TypeScript, object with prop of type bool or () => bool, How to handle?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Vue app. I'm converting vanilla JS to TypeScript and I have this pattern; I have a component that accepts a property item which is an object with several properties following the scheme:

```js
type Button = {
    variant?: 'string' | function(): string;
    ...others...
}
```

Everything works by the idea that it accepts a string or a function that returns a string (it also works for booleans etc...)

In the same component, I have a function that checks if the key is a function and if it is executing it, and returns the result if it is not a function simply passes on whatever it is.

```js
private finalize<K extends keyof Button>(item: Button, key: K, target: Button["target"]): Button[K] {
  let finalized:Button[K]? = null;
  if (identify(item).isObject()) {
    if (identify(item[key]).isFunction()) {
      finalized = item[key](target);
    } else {
      finalized = item[key];
    }
  } else if (item) {
    finalized = item;
  };
  return finalized;
}
```

My problem is that i want to narrow the returned type from a union like -  `string | () => string` - to `string`.
Instead my finalize function return type is still `string | () => string`.
How do I mke TS understand that if it is a function it will execute it

Comment: Assuming, that identify(...).toFunction() correctly implements a typeguard, you should extract `item[key]` as a variable. And could use it like this: `check() { const val = item[key]; if(isString(val)) { /* type is now only string */ } } const isString = <T>(p: T | null | undefined): p is string => typeof p === "string";`

Answer (score 0):

A good solution that'd work for any return type:

```js
function isCallable<T>(value: T | (() => T)): value is (() => T) {
  return value instanceof Function;
}
```

And then you'd use this way:

```js
let myValue: string | () => string;

// Here, myValue should be assigned somethign, otherwise TypeScript will
// complain that it's used before it gets anything assigned. Let's give it
// something and manually type it as `any` so TypeScript is still in the dark
// regarding its true type.
myValue = "hello" as any;

if (isCallable(myValue)) {
  // myValue is narrowed as a function that returns a string
} else {
  // myValue is narrowed as a string
}
```

This will work with any type, thanks to the genericness of the `isCallable` function. It accepts anything that either a type (`T`) or a function that returns the `T` type. Once you call it, and thanks to the `is` keyword in its signature, TypeScript can narrow down the given variable's type.